# Jquery Chained With Multiple values

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2, jquery-chaining

Using Jquery Chained And Select2 With Multiple Options And Chained Select always reference First Selected Option .

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group kt-form__group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Governorate</label>
       <select class="ignoreField auto-select-2 form-control kt-input"
       name="governorate_id[]" id="governorate_id" multiple>
       <option value="">Select An Option</option>
       @foreach($Data["Governorate"] as $governorate)
       <option value="{{$governorate->id}}">
                {{$governorate->name_en}} 
        </option>
       @endforeach
       </select>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group kt-form__group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Zone</label>
       <select class="ignoreField auto-select-2 form-control kt-input"
       name="zone_id[]" id="zone_id" multiple>
       <option value="">Select An Option</option>
       @foreach($Data["Zones"] as $zone)
       <option value="{{$zone->id}}" data-chained="{{$zone->governorate_id}}">
                {{$zone->name_en}} 
        </option>
       @endforeach
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code With Version "jquery_chained-2.x"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#zone_id").chained("#governorate_id");
  </script>
```

Is Jquery Chained Applicable to use With Multiple Options ?